# how to change MBProgressHUD activity indicator style?

Tags: ios, swift4, uiactivityindicatorview

I have integrated MBProgressHUD. It was previously showing small indicator but in swift 4 update or pod update, it is now changed large indicator. They might have changed `UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge` in new pods. So my question is that how can I initialise using `UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite`. I can't see any method to change indicator style. You can check both screenshot after and before.

[image: After] [image: Before]

Any idea how to change?

Answer (score 1):

Write an extension for `MBProgessHUD`. Then customise the properties that are needed.

Comment: Okay, let me try this.

Answer (score 0):

The MBProgressHUD is in cocoapods. so you have to fork their code from github and make the changes that you want.
You can then use the forked code in your project. MBProgressHUD’s MIT license allows you to do so.

Comment: you mean to say, need to change pod lib?

Comment: If the current mbprogressHud doesnt allow you have that option only

Comment: That's what I am trying to find out. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

In order to get the smaller indicator use:

```
UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite
```

That's it!

Comment: I know, but I don't want to change the pod lib. Is there any other way?

Comment: Sure you could probably create an extension in Swift to override it.